# How Can I Block Multiple IP Addresses with PHP

Tags: php, ip

I want to block some BAD users by their IP.

So I need a simple PHP code that can block multiple IP addresses and redirect them to other website.

Now I am using this code

```
<?php
$deny = array("111.111.111", "222.222.222", "333.333.333");
if (preg_match($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], $deny)) {
header("location: http://www.google.com/");
exit();
} ?>
```

Comment: We don't do work for free here.  If you want code, hire a developer.  However, if you're having problems with existing code, post that here and we'll help you.

Comment: If you have tried something and have a problem in getting part of it to work, then great, post some code and we can advise you where you went wrong - but SO isn't a "I want this code..." site.

Comment: Funny how you can rephrase your "need" a bit differently and you'll get people helping you...

Comment: Blocking IP is something ***impossible***. Users now are smart enough to use Proxy, so how could you block them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using preg_match use in_array function, as preg_match accepts 2nd parameter(expression to be matched) as string.

Use the below code :

```
if (in_array($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] , $deny)) {
    header("location: http://www.google.com/");
    exit();
}
```